# Read and transmit JSON file from Express to Jade

Tags: json, express, pug

I'm new to Express and Jade, can't find why Jade tells me the object is undefined.
I've a **big JSON file** about a collectionable card game, which structure is:

```
{
"LEA" : { /* set data */ },
"LEB" : { /* set data */ },
"2ED" : { /* set data */ },
...
}
```

and, for each set

```
              "name" : "Nemesis",           
              "code" : "NMS",                
      "gathererCode" : "NE",                 
           "oldCode" : "NEM",                
"magicCardsInfoCode" : "ne",                 
       "releaseDate" : "2000-02-14"          
            "border" : "black",              
              "type" : "expansion",          


             "block" : "Masques",            
        "onlineOnly" : false,                 
           "booster" : [ "rare", ... ],      
             "cards" : [ {}, {}, {}, ... ]
```

I want to **loop through the array of cards** for a **GETed set** and display some informations about. This is my `cards.js` file

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mtgjson = require('mtgjson');

router.get('/:set?', function(req, res){

    var set = req.params.set;
    if (set === undefined) {
    res.send('respond with a resource');

    } else {

    mtgjson(function(err, data) {
       if (err) return console.log(err);
       res.render('cards', { selectedSet : data.set });                                 
   });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this the jade template

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 #{selectedSet.name}
  ul
  each card in selectedSet.cards
    li #{card.rarity}
```

I'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated, I'm probably making some stupid error.

EDIT: New informations ------------------

When I `console.log(data)` I get the following, it seems right:

```
TOR:
   { name: 'Torment',
     code: 'TOR',
     magicCardsInfoCode: 'tr',
     releaseDate: '2002-02-04',
     border: 'black',
     type: 'expansion',
     block: 'Odyssey',
     booster:
      [ 'rare',
        'uncommon',
         ...
        'common' ],
     cards:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        ...

        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
```

And if I console `set` It gives me the right string ( TOR in this example ).

Edit 2 -------------------------

If I pass the entire `data` object and the `set` variable to the jade template, I can achieve the final result but in a very sub-optimal way. 
I've made something like this

```
block content
  ul
    each val, key in data
      if key == set
        li #{val.name}
          each card in val.cards
            p #{card.name}
```

SOLUTION ----

Just a stupid error: I just messed up with property accessors. I should use `data[set]` instead of `data.set` beacause `var set` is a literal.
See reference http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1

Comment: Does selectedSet have a property called #name?. What does data.set return exactly?

Comment: Yes, each set has a bungh o propreties ( see above ) included "name". data.set should return an object with the proprieties listed above ( see "each set", etc. ).
The fact is that if I use `data.LEA` ( where LEA is the "key" of a se object ) it works, fine. Intead, if I use `data.set` it telss me `undefined` ( the set variable is correctly assigned to LEA, I checked it ).

Comment: the error cannot read property, is exactly that. Make sure when you say data.set, it's returning what you expect. The error is not a jade or express error. The return value of data as you stated above, doesn't show a #set property on data. so data.set will be undefined. just render res.render('cards', { selectedSet : data }); without the set.

Comment: I used the wrong notation to access property, dot instead of square brackets.
Thank you for your useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong notation to access properties. I should use square brackets notation beacause the `var set` is a string literal, in this case the dot notation won't work.
[See reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `selectedSet.cards.rarity` instead of `cards.rarity`. The only object you are passing to the template is your `selectedSet` object, and `cards` is nested within that.

Comment: I found it was just an error with property accessors, I should use square bracket notation. Thank you.